# Load 50K records to DynamoDB from JSON or CSV

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a csv or 50K records as well JSON document of 50K records. The file or document is an array of geo locations.

My objective is to load all 50K records into DynamoDB. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Currently it looks like there is a limitation of maximum 25 records I can load at once which is a very long-time process to load all 50K records into DynamoDB.

The JSON file size is around 70 MB.

Is there any way to load all 50K records from the JSON which holds array of objects? Or any way to load from CSV? I am able to do load from java code. But I am mainly looking some dynamodb command or tools where I should be able to load.

One single JSON object looks like below:

```
"PutRequest": { 
    "Item": { 
        "id": {"S":"1"},
        "zipcode": {"S":"501"},
        "city": {"S":"HOLTSVILLE"},
        "state": {"S":"NY"},
        "county_name": {"S":"SUFFOLK"},
        "area_codes": {"S":"631"},
        "city_type": {"S":"Non Postal Community Name"},
        "city_abbr": {"S":""},
        "city_alias": {"S":"I R S SERVICE CENTER"},
        "latitude": {"S":"40.81518"},
        "longitude": {"S":"-73.0455"},
        "time_zone_offset": {"S":"5"},
        "elevation": {"S":"25"},
        "county_fips": {"S":"103"},
        "daylight_savings_flag": {"S":"Y"},
        "preferred_last_line_key": {"S":"V13916"},
        "classification_code": {"S":"U"},
        "multi_county_flag": {"S":" "},
        "state_fips": {"S":"36"},
        "city_state_key": {"S":"V13995"},
        "time_zone": {"S":"America/New_York"},
        "daylight_savings": {"S":"1"},
        "updated_at": {"S":"2/26/2009 0:00"},
        "city_alias_code": {"S":"NULL"},
        "primary_record": {"S":"NULL"},
        "city_mixed_case": {"S":"NULL"},
        "city_alias_mixed_case": {"S":"NULL"},
        "state_ansi": {"S":"NULL"},
        "county_ansi": {"S":"NULL"},
        "facility_code": {"S":"NULL"},
        "unique_zip_name": {"S":"NULL"},
        "city_delivery_indicator": {"S":"NULL"},
        "carrier_route_rate_sortation": {"S":"NULL"},
        "finance_number": {"S":"NULL"},
        "unique_id": {"S":"NULL"},
        "created_at": {"S":"NULL"},
        "country_code": {"S":"US"}
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Published an article a few months ago on this very topic.  You can check it out [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-bulk-csv-ingestion-to-amazon-dynamodb/).